# How to make filerdear to read input file path from filechooser

Tags: java

i'm having this filereader  that normaly read's a file from path in source.
i made a filchooser but i don't know how to add this filereader to get the filepath from file chooser.

Code for FileReader below

```
StringBuilder resultKamera = new StringBuilder();

 {

 try  {


    brKamera = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\path.xxx"));
     while ((lineKamera = brKamera.readLine()) != null) {

     Matcher categoryMatcherKamera = CategorieKamera.matcher(lineKamera);                   
     Matcher itemMatcherKamera = CategorieSiCantitateKamera.matcher(lineKamera);
```

Code For FileChooser bleow:

```
 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
              chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
              chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
              chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
              chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

               if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                       System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
               } else {
                 System.out.println("No Selection ");
               }

        }
     });
```

Comment: I don't get the question, you want to read the selected file? Then use chooser.getSelectedFile() no?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno , yes but it ask me to create a local variable chooser. I got the Filereader and JfileChooser in same class. but the Filereader is added to a button action, and JfileChooser is added to a menu

Comment: Well, you could save the selected file somewhere if you don't want to execute the reading code as soon as the user selects the file